# Not able to understand how values in loop work

Tags: c, cs50

I tried writing code for cs50 pset1's problem: credit.c(more comfortable) after week2. My code is given below. The problem is that 'sumx' and 'sumy' are just 0 and hence 'sum' is always equal to 0. So whenever I give a correct credit card number, it is just going to new line and program ends. How can I solve this problem and why are 'sumx' and 'sumy' not adding up to their respective sums as they should according to the algorithm?

My code is:

```
#include <cs50.h>     
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

  long long i;
  do{
    printf("Your credit card number:\n");   
    i = get_long_long();
  }
  while(i < 4e12 || i > 5.5e15);
  int count = 0;
  int n;
  long long c = i;

  while(i != 0){
    n = i%10;
    i = i/10;
    count++;
  }
  int x[count];

  for(int j = 0; j < count; j++){
    x[j] = c%10;
    i = c/10;
  }

  int sumx = 0;

  for(int j = 0; j < count - 1; j += 2){
    x[j] = x[j] * 2;
    sumx = sumx + x[j];
    printf("%i", sumx);
  }

  int sumy = 0;

  for(int j = 0; j < count; j += 2){
    sumy = sumy + x[j];
  }  

  int sum;
  sum = sumx + sumy;

  if(sum%10 == 0){
    if((count == 15 && x[14] == 3) && (x[13] == 4 || x[13] == 7)){
        printf("AmEx\n");
    }
    else if((count == 16 && x[15] == 5) && (x[14] > 1 || x[14] < 5)){
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    else if((count == 13 && x[12] == 4) || (count == 16 && x[15] == 4)){
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
  }
  else{
    printf("Invalid Number\n");
  }

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

Comment: `n` is unused..

Comment: `i = i/10;` you reduce `i` down to 0 when working out `count`. Then you do `x[j] = i%10;` in a loop to fill the `x` array, but `i` is already 0 so this can't work. You need to reset `i` to the credit card number again first.

Comment: Your loops never run because your loop condition is never true, so `sumx` and `sumy` keep their original value of 0.

Comment: I edited the code so as to make long long c = i but still it isn't working. Why are my loop conditions false?

Comment: Because `j` isn't 0.

Comment: Changed it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to run the program step by step and query its state, so understanding better what happens.

Comment: seems you don't know what do you want. please try your problem in pen&paper before start coding. if you solve question on paper %99 of work is done.

Comment: if you explain what these lines do may i can help to fix,   int sumx = 0;

  for(int j = 0; j < count - 1; j += 2){
    x[j] = x[j] * 2;
    sumx = sumx + x[j];
    printf("%i", sumx);
  }

  int sumy = 0;

  for(int j = 0; j < count; j += 2){
    sumy = sumy + x[j];
  }  

  int sum;
  sum = sumx + sumy;

Comment: sumx is twice the sum of the alternate digits of the long long number starting from the second to last digit and sumy is the sum of the remaining digits of the long long number

Comment: @TejeshAtr again ,as Basil comments...  debugger.  If you have not, or cannot demsonstrate, any debugging, you should try that first before posting code and 'Still doesn't work' to SO :(

Answer (score 0):

```
//#include <cs50.h>     
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

  long long i=4111111111111111;
  //Master: 5105105105105100;//16
  //visa: 4111111111111111
  printf("%lld\n",i);

  //~ do{
    //~ printf("Your credit card number:\n");   
    //~ i = get_long_long();
  //~ }
  //~ while(i < 4e12 || i > 5.5e15);


  int count = 0;
  long long c = i;
  int k=0;
  int x[100];//

  while(c != 0){
    x[k] = c%10;
    c = c/10;
    printf("%lld\n",c);
    count++;
    k++;
  }

  //k==count
  printf("count:%d\n",count);
  printf("k:%d\n",k);

    // x[i] contains all the digits of credit card
    printf("print x[i]\n");
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
        printf("%d ",x[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");


    int addsum=0,x2prod=0;

     for (int j=0; j<k; j+=2 ){
        addsum += x[j];
    }   

 printf("addsum:%d\n",addsum);



    for (int j=1; j<k; j+=2 ){
        if ( (2 * x[j]) > 9 ){ //have 2 digit
            x2prod += (2 * x[j]) / 10;
            x2prod += (2 * x[j]) % 10;
        }
        else // have one digit
            x2prod += 2 * x[j];
    }   


    printf("x2prod:%d\n",x2prod);

    int sum; 

    sum = addsum + x2prod;


  printf("\nsum: %d\n",sum);

  if(sum%10 == 0){
    if((count == 15 && x[14] == 3) && (x[13] == 4 || x[13] == 7)){
        printf("AmEx\n");
    }
    else if((count == 16 && x[15] == 5) && (x[14] > 1 || x[14] < 5)){
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    else if((count == 13 && x[12] == 4) || (count == 16 && x[15] == 4)){
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
  }
  else{
    printf("Invalid Number\n");
  }

  return 0;
  }
```

I apply some correction on your code, store all credit card digits on `x[]`array in  first `while()`.

I checked code output with only three samples and by the way this is not a reliable version, try to catch any error.

As you read on my comment i don't any idea about that, but by perform simple search this [link](https://github.com/callahanchris/CS50/blob/master/pset1/credit%20card.c)

show me what to do and decode it to your way.